# fetchrow_hashref issue in perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I am not able to retrieve the output properly using the below code. Please help me to sort it out.

I am getting output differently to run in MySQL and Perl.

As of now it is returning undef when I use Dumper. But I want it to display null.

```
    $reactivate_sth = $dbh->prepare("
      SELECT
        a,
        b
      FROM
        table
      WHERE
        c = ?
      AND
        d = ?
      ORDER BY
        date DESC
    ");
$reactivate_sth->execute($c, $d);
print $result = $reactivate_sth->fetchrow_hashref();
```

OUTPUT:

MySQL:

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Perl:

```
HASH(0x3068198)
```

Data::Dumper

```
VAR1 = undef
```

Comment: What does `Data::Dumper` show the `$result` hash contains? Also, is the MySQL under a transactional state (that may require a `commit`)?

Comment: What @DravSloan said. Also, are you sure that you're connecting to the same database instance in both cases?

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that you can validate an "empty" result from `fetchrow_hashref()` by issuing `if(!%$result)`. Testing an empty hash will return false if it has no key/value pairs. (you have to prefix your hash with the `%` operator because it is a hash reference).

Comment: @DravSloan: That is bad advice. If there were no rows found then the `fetchrow_hashref` method will return `undef`.

Comment: Oh yeah that's a bad mistake, so it should of read `if(!defined $result || !%$result) { ... }`

Comment: `print($var);` and `print(Dumper($var));` can't possibly output `HASH(0x3068198)` and `$VAR1 = undef` for the same `$var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for this issue. I am not sure this one is a proper fix or not.

Please guide me if the fix is not professional.

```
if (!defined $result->{''}) {
   $result = '';
}
```

Comment: Try this if( keys %hash ) {
    # There are keys
} else {
    # There are no keys
}

Answer (score 2):

You must make your code more readable. It's often useful to use a *heredoc* to quote SQL statements, like this

```
my $reactivate_sth = $dbh->prepare(<<END_SQL);
SELECT a, b
FROM table
WHERE c = ? AND d = ?
ORDER BY date DESC
END_SQL

$reactivate_sth->execute($c, $d);

my $result = $reactivate_sth->fetchrow_hashref;
```

Now `$result` is a *reference to a hash*, because you called the `fetchrow_hashref` method. Printing it will, as you have found, produce something like `HASH(0x1cc5a8)`. You need to access the *elements* of the hash to make sense of the result

After that, I don't know what output you want. You can use the core `Data::Dumper` module to display the record that you've retrieved like this

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $result;
```

Does that help? You haven't asked for anything more

Comment: I did not get `execute($c, $d)` part. Can you please explain how it works as I have no idea .

Comment: @Arijit: Please don't hijack someone else's question. If you want to ask something then please post a question of your own.

Comment: @Borodin: mysql returns empty set of record. But dumper prints undef. I don't want to display undef.

Comment: @Vasanth: You should put exactly what you see into the question. Everything is useful. A result of `undef` means that there was nothing found for the SELECT statement.

Comment: @Borodin - I use this question answer platform to gain knowledge. try to understand each question and answer. I tried to understand your answer also. But I failed.

Comment: @Arijit: Then ask another question.

Comment: @Arijit: In my opinion you must reassess your relationship with Stack Overflow. You seem to treat it as an ordinary forum, whereas it is much more like a *wiki*, where every submission must be well-formed question or answer. [Your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3835621/arijit) have a total of three votes over ten questions, while the votes on your answers have a negative total. Something is going wrong, and I urge you to take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) again.

Comment: @Borodin :- I always appreciate your comments, feedback  and I strongly believe the votes on my answers are positive in total and I treat it as a special platform to gain and share knowledge. Though my start in stake overflow was not good. I got some negative feedback in my questions.

Comment: @Arijit: I am sure that you have a lot to offer. But please make sure that your posts are correct (you have tested them) and offer something new. That applies to both questions and answers.